# How to restore drive mount after DeleteVolumeMountPoint?

Tags: c++, windows, hard-drive, wdk

After using DeleteVolumeMountPoint("E:\") (for instance) in order to delete the mounting point of a DOK, i would like to restore it. (make the drive letter usable again)

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the MSDN documentation for [DeleteVolumeMountPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that [SetVolumeMountPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would do the task.

The documentation [links to an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE MAX_PATH 

int _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
   BOOL bFlag;
   TCHAR Buf[BUFSIZE];     // temporary buffer for volume name

   if( argc != 3 ) 
   {
      _tprintf( TEXT("Usage: %s <mount_point> <volume>\n"), argv[0] );
      _tprintf( TEXT("For example, \"%s c:\\mnt\\fdrive\\ f:\\\"\n"), argv[0]);
      return( -1 );
   }

  // We should do some error checking on the inputs. Make sure there 
  // are colons and backslashes in the right places, and so on 

   bFlag = GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(
              argv[2], // input volume mount point or directory
                  Buf, // output volume name buffer
              BUFSIZE  // size of volume name buffer
           );

   if (bFlag != TRUE) 
   {
      _tprintf( TEXT("Retrieving volume name for %s failed.\n"), argv[2] );
      return (-2);
   }

   _tprintf( TEXT("Volume name of %s is %s\n"), argv[2], Buf );
   bFlag = SetVolumeMountPoint(
              argv[1], // mount point
                  Buf  // volume to be mounted
           );

   if (!bFlag)
     _tprintf (TEXT("Attempt to mount %s at %s failed.\n"), argv[2], argv[1]);

   return (bFlag);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For just doing it interactively you can open the 'Volume Manager', right click on the volume and assign a drive letter.